# Notification if requestWhenInUseAuthorization failed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a sort of locationServices permission authentication, where you only can use the app if it has permission to locationServices. Therefore if the user declines `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` it should present a viewController with info about this. However i can't seem to get a notification if the user declined this. What is the best solution for this? or should consider to achieve this another way?

```
func determinePermission() {

    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {

    case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

        }

    case .NotDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    case .Restricted, .Denied:

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PermissionController") as! PermissionViewController

        self.parentViewController!.tabBarController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add code to show your current implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol.`CLLocationManagerDelegate` has `locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)`  method which gets called when authorisation status is changed.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:

    case .AuthorizedAlways:
        // you have access
        break

    case .Denied : 

    default:
        // you don't have access. add your code here to present new view
        break
    }
}
```